# Ui-sref not generating clickable links/not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I used ng-route for this before and it worked fine, but with UI Router, the links are not clickable anymore, or at least most of the time they aren't. When they are, which is very random, they don't display the html templates I'm using.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Tutorial</title>

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

   <ng-view></ng-view>

    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a ui-sref="view1">view1</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="view2">view2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'myApp.controllers',
    'ui.router'
    ]);

angular.module('myApp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('view1',{
        url: '/view1',
        controller:'Controller1',
        templateUrl:'/view1.html' 
    }).state('view2', {
        url: '/view2/:firstname/:lastname',
        controller: 'Controller2',
        resolve: {
            names: function() {
                return ['Misko', 'Vojta', 'Brad'];
            }
        },
        templateUrl: '/view2.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/view1');

});


angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('Controller1', function($scope, $location, $state) {

    $scope.loadView2=function() {
        $state.go('view2', {
            firstname: $scope.firstname,
            lastname: $scope.lastname
        });
    };
}).controller('Controller2', function($scope, $stateParams, names) {
    $scope.firstname = $stateParams.firstname;
    $scope.lastname = $stateParams.lastname;
    $scope.names = names;

});
```

I'm following the instructions in the SitePoint ebook on AngularJS, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong or what I missed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/amh3nZmyB7lC2IQi3DIn

Comment: I don't see a `ui-view` anywhere in your markup, so your states' views are most likely not being rendered and injected

Comment: @JAAulde Should I use that instead of ng-view or in conjunction with it?

Comment: A single `ui-view` should exist in your main HTML file. Your top level states will be rendered and injected there. You should not need `ng-view`. States can have substates, and each template of a state which has a substate should have a `ui-view` where its rendered substates will be injected.

Comment: Look through `ui-router`'s readme for the basics of getting it working: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/README.md . Also, they have a good demo app you can download and look through which really helped me understand what this state routing engine is about and how to use it.

Comment: Cool. I've copied my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see a `ui-view` anywhere in your markup, so your states' views are most likely not being rendered and injected.

You should not need `ng-view`. A single `ui-view` should exist in your main HTML file. Your top level states will be rendered and injected there. States can have substates, and each template of a state which has a substate should have a `ui-view` of its own where its rendered substates will be injected.

Look through [`ui-router`'s readme](http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/README.md) for the basics of getting it working. Also, they have a good [demo app](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/), the source of which really helped me understand what this state routing engine is about and how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Helpful info, hopefully...

Although the answers above are correct (missing `ui-view`, referencing `ui.router`, etc.), I have run into situations where other problems with the load of a view will cause links to not be generated.  For example, this morning I forgot to reference the module `angular-cache` and was running into a problem with `CacheFactory` not loading (completely unrelated to `ui.router`).  Until the references were resolved, `ui.router` was dead in the water.

Comment: This helped me. I was having an unrelated error (null checking) and it was preventing the default behavior of ui-sref. Thanks!